# Internet Explorer expired cookies not null

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

Well, im working with cookies and I'm having troubles with (surprise) Internet Explorer.

I have this code:

```
if(readCookie('cooldown')!=null) return;
```

On Firefox when a cookie expires it returns `null`, but on IE, it returns the cookie itself. So I want to catch if a cookie expired. Maybe a solution could be to get the current `Date`, and compare it with the cookie `Date`, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

NOTE: I stored the date in the cookie. Example:

```
value = "0,expireDate=Thu May 29 2014 13:56:58 GMT+0200"
```

EDIT: `readCookie` method:

```
function readCookie(name){
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) { return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length); }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's Internet Explorer 10

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just added the readCookie method.